# Create/rename a file/folder that begins with a dot in Windows?

Tags: windows

Many programs needs folder names that starts with a dot, like `.emacs.d`, `.gimp-2.2`, `.jedit` etc. How do I create such a folder?

When using the Windows Explorer in Windows 2000 (and other versions), I get an error message saying "You have to enter a filename". The only solution I have come up with, is to open a command prompt (Start > Run > "CMD" > OK) and enter `mkdir .mydir`.

Why have Microsoft this error message in the Explorer, but not in the command shell? Is there any registry hack out there to fix this, so that I am able to enter the folder name directly in the Explorer?

Comment: This is an ancient protection built into windows explorer and dates back to the time that only DOS 8.3 filenames were available (Win 3.1) and files with just an extension were not allowed. Microsoft never bothered to remove this from the Explorer, probably because humans using the Explorer should be "protected" from accidentally creating files without a filename (i.e., only extension).

Comment: See also "How do I rename a file to .htaccess in Windows 7?" at http://superuser.com/questions/56562/how-do-i-rename-a-file-to-htaccess-in-windows-7/

Comment: Related post on SO - [How to manually create a file with a . dot prefix in windows for example .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5004633/465053)

Comment: I encountered a similar problem when creating files. Some files were named`com4.txt`, `com1.txt` etc and those are reserved names for devices, so it crashed my software.

Comment: Also, perhaps to somewhat clarify re the good initial comment above: the '8.3' in the comment refers to the naming convention at that time of _xxxxxxxx.xxx_, or _filename.ext_,  referring to the fact that maximum filename length at that time for those systems was 8 characters,.separated by a dot, and the 3 for the length of extension characters, cf referring to a DOS Version such as DOS 3.1, DOS 3.3, or DOS 5.0 , Thank you :)

Answer (score 713):

To **create/rename on windows explorer**, just rename to `.name.` - The additional dot at the end is necessary, and will be removed by Windows Explorer.

To create a new file begins with a dot, on command prompt:

```
echo testing > .name
```

Comment: I just tried `.name.` in Windows (XP) and it did not work; it complained about needing a filename.

Comment: Confirmed to work on Windows 7. That's awesome.

Comment: Confirmed to work on Windows 8.

Comment: Confirmed to work on Windows Vista. Amazing.

Comment: Only option to create in XP is thru command prompt. say `mkdir .name`

Comment: Or even simply `echo. > .name`!

Comment: Works on Windows 10 - @Denny where did you find this gold nugget?!

Comment: @Denny How did you know this? Is it a feature or a very useful bug?

Comment: @ButtleButkus (not meant to disparage *anyone*) ...I would imagine that he knew this because he is older than 30 and had to make his way in the Long-Long-Ago; in the Before Time when theres was no Interwebz.  Try this little ditty from your command line `echo times >> .foo & < nul (set /p s=gaz) >> .foo & echo intas >> .foo & type .foo` and you will see 2 lines printed to the screen `times` and `gazintas`

Comment: @K.AlanBates I don't see an explanation in your comment regarding the trailing dot. What does age or the internet have to do with this syntactical phenomenon?

Comment: if you get "The system cannot find the file specified." when trying to rename/move, make sure the file or folder isn't hidden! (`attrib -h .setting && move .setting .new-setting`)

Comment: @K.AlanBates - A little less patronisation, a little more explanation please.

Comment: Works with windows 2008 R2 SP1, which is the server equivalent of Win7.  Thank you OP and @Joe White

Comment: `echo on > .name` (or `echo off > .name`) creates an empty file.

Comment: @Hashim The original DOS convention for filenames was FILENAME.EXT where the dot separator was always present at least implicitly to separate the name from the extension. For backwards compatibility or tradition, Windows still works like this, so any filename ending with a . is the same as the name itself. For example "abc." is the same as "abc", as is "abc..", "abc..." and so on. On Unix-like systems these are all distinct filenames, but on Windows they are not.

Comment: For those keeping score, this is confirmed to work in Windows Server 2012

Comment: For those keeping score, this is confirmed to work in Windows Server 2016

Answer (score 71):

You can create a folder using the Command Prompt with:

`mkdir .foldername`

You can create a file using command prompt with:

`echo.>.filename.extension`

Answer (score 39):

Good question. There is an easy way to do this from Windows Explorer without using a command prompt or shell. Suppose you want to create a folder called: "`.apple`"

1. Create a New Folder from Windows Explorer as you normally would.
2. When prompted to enter a name, type: "`.apple.`" (notice the dot at the end)

Windows should create a folder called: "`.apple`"

Please note that I've used this only on Windows 7. I am not sure if other versions of Windows support this.

P.S. Chris Moschini says [in a comment](https://superuser.com/q/64471/150988#comment1835469_1156507) that it works in Windows 10.

Comment: Works in Windows 10.

Comment: this was exactly the same as the [top voted answer in this question](https://superuser.com/a/406758/241386), only 4 years later

Comment: You have just saved my life, I accidentally rename all folders and files from my Windows User folder and my programs started to fail. Fortunately i was able to reset the names. +1e6 votes up.

Answer (score 14):

Use any file browser other than Explorer (Shell). I have tested with WinRAR, 7-Zip ect. For example, open WinRAR, then navigate to your files or folders, click on it, press <kbd>F2</kbd> (rename), put a `.` at beginning, Done! I have tested with both WinRAR and 7-Zip. You don't need to add to Zip or make a compressed file.

The simpler method I found in other answer, just put a `.` at the end too.

Answer (score 8):

Open a Command Prompt window and enter the following commands:

```
cd /path/to/the/file
ren file.extension .file.extension
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with powershell cmdlet `New-Item`.

Open PowerShell console and enter

For File:

```
New-Item .whatever -type file
```

For Folder:

```
New-Item .whatever -type directory
```

Comment: Yeah, in Powershell 4.0 also works with "md" command.

Answer (score 4):

[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) does it in visual manner.

Answer (score 2):

Use Windows Powershell. Otherwise this is not possible with DOS/Explorer - only method is to create foo.bar and then rename with the explorer window.

With Powershell you can

`touch .bak`

successfully.

Comment: this is definitely possible. Did you look at the [most voted answer](https://superuser.com/a/406758/241386) which was posted several months before yours?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't create `.bowerrc`. So

First, I created bowerrc
Then, to a dos prompt I said:

```
>powershell
PS > ren bowerrc .bowerrc
PS > exit
>
```

Comment: you dont even need powershell.  just plain old cmd (see other answers) - Powershell definitely works though :)

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way to do this:
I have ConEmu installed and integrated into the Windows context menu. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852965/open-in-conemu-right-click-menu-windows-7

When I need to rename a file to one with the dot I choose "ConEmu here" from the context menu, then type:

```
ren name .name
```

Can also be used with `echo` method above.

Benefits:

- Quick and easy, doesn't take you out of context too much.
- No need to type `D: enter cd D:\\____\\_____\\_______\\____`
- No need to install software you wouldn't otherwise (I like and use ConEmu for various purposes).

Answer (score 0):

Just download Anyclient and Fast Folder Rename. Fast folder rename will name a folder .whatever, using the replace feature. Anyclient will upload the folder and show it, even though it operates on a Windows system.

Comment: links to the utilities would be very useful

Answer (score -4):

Windows (Explorer) does not allow you to create a folder that starts with a dot ('.'). This is for security/exploit reasons. However, it is possible (as you noted) to create the folder manually using the Command Prompt.

So, if your question was how to do it in native Windows Explorer, the answer is no -- You cannot.

Comment: How do you do it from the command line?

Comment: *> Windows (Explorer) does not allow you to create a folder that starts with a dot ('.'). This is for security/exploit reasons.*   Huh? In what way?

Comment: I second Synetech comment - if it is for "security/exploit reasons" then we need to call up Linus Torvald ASAP and tell him to plug this hole yesterday!