# How do I create a folder name that starts with a dot in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I'm on a Windows 7 machine and need to create a new folder whose name starts with a dot. To be specific, I need to create the folder "**C:\USERS\theusername\.ec2**" because that is the default location that the AWS plugin for Eclipse likes to find certain configuration files.

Windows 7 gives me an error message whenever I try to create a folder that starts with a dot:

> You must type a filename

Seriously? There are already subfolders in this folder that start with a dot!

How can I tell Windows 7 to just shut up and create my folder?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1. From the folder above the parent for the new folder, shift-right click on the parent, choose "Open command prompt here".
2. Type `mkdir .ec2` (enter)
3. Close the command prompt

Comment: This is what I have been doing but it just seemed wrong. At least now I know I'm not crazy.

Comment: you can do the same without opening the command prompt by just typing the command into the directory bar (see my answer) skips 2 steps :)

Answer (score 57):

This behavior is based on a "feature" of dos 8.3 where it was forbidden to have a file without a name.

Name the folder `.name.`

So the Explorer thinks you will create a file with a name but no extension(which is allowed).
The explorer will then delete the dot at the end because it is unnecessary.

Comment: This is a simple and very elegant solution!

Comment: @erik-schierboom, I hope you are referring to this answer, rather than to the solution provided by Microsoft ;-)

Answer (score 7):

From [here](https://superuser.com/questions/64471/create-rename-a-file-folder-that-begins-with-a-dot-in-windows).

To **create/rename on windows explorer**, just rename to `.name.`

The additional dot at the end is unnecessary, and will be removed by Windows Explorer.

In windows 8 (possibly 7) you can also type directly into the navigation bar "mkdir .name" without needing to open a command prompt

[image]

Comment: Renaming inside windows explorer can still result in automatic changes to case, etc.  Do you know if this is special handling for `mkdir` or whether other CMD.exe built-in commands work also?

Comment: all commands executed from the bar are as if launched from cmd.exe within that folder. example I can run a git command or `composer update` and it opens the window there and runs the command

Comment: You can type search terms into the navigation bar, and they might unintentionally get interpreted as commands? Am I missing something, or is that as disturbing as it sounds?

Comment: @LarsH is that Windows 10 behavior? AFAIK 8 and lower did not have search in the navigation bar

Comment: in windows 7 just opens bing search

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this is:

1. Start > Run > `cmd` > OK
2. Enter:

   ```
   mkdir .yourfoldername
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the command line. Hold shift and right click in the directory you'd like to create a subdirectory in. Choose the "Open Command Prompt here" (or something like that) item. In it, type:

```
md .ec2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from `CMD`. Navigate to where you need then

```
mkdir ".folder"
```