# How do I rename a file or folder to .something in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, rename, file-extension

When I try to rename a folder to `.svn` or a file to `.myemacs`, for example, a popup says:

> You must specify a file name.

Do you have a workaround ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create/rename a file/folder that begins with a dot in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/64471/create-rename-a-file-folder-that-begins-with-a-dot-in-windows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open cmd

Start -> Run -> "cmd"

then

```
move filename.txt .svn
```

Comment: Good solution indeed. I could have thought about that, I even have cygwin installed so I could do it with `mv` command. But I am interested if there is a less geeky way

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with the **geeky** way?

Comment: SVN, Emacs and Cygwin aren't geeky?

Comment: Note that if you initially renamed the .svn directory, and are trying to move it back, you might have to uncheck the 'hidden' box on the directory's Properties dialog before this will work.