# Do hidden files copied onto a USB from Windows 7 appear as hidden in OS X?

Tags: windows, macos

Do hidden files copied onto a USB drive from Windows 7 appear as hidden in OS X?

Or does OS X show them as visible?

Comment: Ali, maybe you could select an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Anything that `attrib` displays with an H on a Windows command line will also be hidden on a Mac via Finder, but will be visible with `ls` on the command line. In other words, Finder will honor the hidden flag, but the Unix command line will not.

Comment: How about a file hidden on Windows using the normal Right Click > Properties > Hide way - will it show hidden in a finder?

Comment: that is the same hidden flag that attrib will show, so no, it will not show up in Finder. I should also mention that Finder has the ability to view hidden files with a certain option set, just like Explorer, so if that is set, the file will then be visible.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to create a file that is hidden in Windows AND OS X consider putting a period at the beginning of the folder/directory name or the file name.  Here's how to do that in [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/64471/create-rename-a-file-folder-that-begins-with-a-dot-in-windows).  OS X sees files/folders that begin with a dot (.) as hidden.  There's a little work to make this happen in Windows, but the end result will be a hidden file in OS X.  Understand that you would still have to set the hidden flag for Windows to see the file as hidden.  Also know that anyone that knows to look for the file, could still find it in OS X.  This just makes it not obviously there...