# Automatically rename worksheet based on filename

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to rename my first sheet or tab in excel based on the file name. If I change the file name, I want the first sheet to be automatically renamed. I don't want .xlsx to be included. I tried this macro:

```
Sub RenameSheet()
Dim myname
myname = Replace(ActiveWorkbook. Name, ".xls", "")
    ActiveSheet.Select
    ActiveSheet.Name = myname
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

but it's not automatically renamed.

Comment: thanks for your help.. i have another question. what formula can i put to my cell A2, so that my file name appear also in this cell automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Insert this code under `ThisWorkbook`. It will rename your first sheet according to your current filename.

Remember that you can not change a filename while the file itself is opened in Excel. 
Due to this, you can utilize the [`Workbook_open()`](http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-programming-event-excel-vba.html) event which is triggered one time when the file is opening.

[InStrRev](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instrrev.php) searches from right to left the first occurens of a Point (.) to know where to cut off the extension with a [Left](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/left.php) function.

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()
    Count = InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".")
    If Count > 0 Then
        Sheets(1).Name = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Count - 1)
        Sheets(1).Range("A2") = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Count - 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Won't this keep doing it every time the file's opened, even when it's no longer needed?

Comment: @martineau As I understand the question this is exactly what he/she wants: `Automatically rename [...]` and `but it's not automatically renamed.`

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it would need to stay in place in case the filename gets changed later. +1

Comment: I would test if `Count > 0`. If not, then use `ThisWorkbook.Name`.

Comment: @peon In case the filename is renamed via [`cmd`](http://superuser.com/a/406758/50173)? :)

Comment: @nixda because you can create in memory or open a valid Excel workbook even if it does not have the appropriate extension.

Comment: @Peon Ouh, you're right. Done

Comment: thanks for your help nixda.. i have another question. what formula can i put to my cell A2, so that my file name appear also in this cell automatically?

Comment: @grace I've added your second request