# Unable to delete / move file from HDD

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, file-permissions

*Not a duplicate. I'm only adding this after trying out everything in other questions*

I recently copied a folder from a friend onto my HDD, and I'm now unable to delete the folder. ( No error message shows up. I select the folder and hit delete, and nothing happens )

I tried the following:

1. Using the regular command line delete option ( del folder )
2. Using the commands given in the following thread:

   [Windows Unable to Delete ._. File](https://superuser.com/questions/997590/windows-unable-to-delete-file)
   del "\?\F:\folder"
3. I couldn't use FileAssassin as there are **no** files inside the folder.
4. I tried using Erase (the "erase on restart" doesn't work. When I try to erase instantly or manually, it stops and windows shows me that the program has started working.) When I tried right clicking on the folder and then clicking on erase, it asks me if I'm sure and then when I hit yes, nothing happens. I couldn't "Secure Move" it either
5. I tried changing the permissions of the folder - I couldn't change it. Error Message: "Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied"
6. Tried moving the files into my laptop and then deleting it. ( Unable to move )

The folder is empty. It's a game folder. The folder list goes as follows: gmW >> cstrike >> sound >> (this goes into the problem folder. It is because of this folder that I'm unable to delete the whole thing. When I try to open this folder, it shows error message: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable )

I understand that formatting the HDD is an option. The problem is that it has over 800 GB of data and I can't copy the onto my laptop (storage is not sufficient) I don't have any other hard drives either.

I scanned for viruses (Kaspersky) and there are none. The size of the folder is 0 bytes.

Is there **any** way to get rid of this file without formattting? Also, what could be the problem here.

Comment: Have you tried running `chkdsk`?

Comment: Okay, I just ran chkdsk and tried deleting the folder. Thank you! And sorry if this was something too trivial to ask here.

Comment: It worked? You were able to delete the folder?

Comment: Yes, it worked like a charm. I ran `chkdsk` and it told me that it discovered errors in certain indices of the HDD. 

And so I ran the 
    `chkdsk /f F:` command to fix the drive. 

There was freespace marked as allocated, and some "orphan files" ( don't know what that means). It completed the re-allocation and I was able to delete the file.

Comment: Great! Just so you know the clue for me was "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

( Adding an answer just to mark this question as solved )

As suggested by @DavidPostill, I tried running `chkdsk` on my HDD. Once I did that, it told me that there errors in certain indices of the file.

And so I ran a `chkdsk /f F:` command to fix the drive. I was then able to delete the folder.

[image: CMD Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use `rmdir /S <dirname>` from a command prompt opened with admin privileges.