# Cannot delete or rename file on desktop

Tags: windows-10

It is c++ compiled .exe file

On deleting this file it shows Deletion Permission:

[image: Deletion Permission]

And on clicking over Continue it gets stuck in try again loop:

[image: Try Again]

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for duplicate question

In case anyone needs help, these are the steps

- Open command prompt with administrative privileges
- Run **chkdsk**
- Run **chkdsk /f "Drive letter" in my case it was **chkdsk /f C:**
- It may ask for restart, after restarting my PC I was able to delete the file.

Credits for answer
[Answered by WorldGov](https://superuser.com/questions/1035350/unable-to-delete-move-file-from-hdd?rq=1)

Comment: Its more likely that the file was still in use. I've had it on my end too. Developing a program, crashing every time I pressed run because apparently the program was still running in the background. Because of that, it has a lock on it. Closing the file from task manager or restarting the computer helps. In your case, you restarted for a different reason.