# Filenames beginning with a period

Tags: windows, filesystems, filenames

Will Renaming files from say "dot myfile" to ".myfile" cause the filesystem or some other part of Windows to somehow freak out in any sort of way.

I have around 3 oe 4 files so far like this, and I use the rename command to accomplish this.

I wouldn't want to lose my data, and I have seen the NTFS filesystem and do some wacky and strange things before, some of it was interesting, and some of it was painfully annoying.

I have around 6 files (but more to com) which have filesnames such as "dot net passport wizard.bmp", however I want it to be called the real thing, which is ".net passport wizard.bmp" (this refers to Microsoft .net Framework).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create/rename a file/folder that begins with a dot in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/64471/create-rename-a-file-folder-that-begins-with-a-dot-in-windows)

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate suggestion. That question is about *how* to create a file with such a name; this is about whether there are any gotchas in doing so. (This might still be a duplicate of something, but that particular question isn't it.)

Answer (score 4):

Dotfiles aren't a problem for the NTFS filesystem.

However, personally, I wouldn't use a filename starting with `.` just to spell ".net". Among tools that recognise them (unix and cross-platform tools), dotfiles are hidden files used for customization, so they may be hidden by default in file managers, etc.