# Save a file with a dot prefix from within a Windows web browser

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, filenames

Does anyone know how to save a file with a name like '.apirc' from a web browser such as Firefox or Chrome in Windows?

The only way I can see to do it is to save the file with the wrong name from the web browser and then use on of the renaming techniques described in [Create/rename a file/folder that begins with a dot in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/64471/create-rename-a-file-folder-that-begins-with-a-dot-in-windows)

However, I'd like to find a one-step way to do it, for our users.

If you know a code solution I have posted a separate version of this question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814114/using-the-html-download-attribute-to-download-a-data-url-as-a-file-beginning-wit

Answer (score 1):

When you have the Save File dialog open, make sure you have the Type set to **All Files (*.*)**. When you do this, the filename will end up exactly as you type it, with nothing added. This works on pretty much any Windows Save dialog in most programs that look like this.

[image: Screenshot of save dialog]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I should have said that I always set to 'All files' and I've also tried putting speech marks around the name. The issue I'm having is that the browser won't let me save a file starting with a dot. Does your browser allow you to 'save as' a file beginning with a dot (if so, what browser and version do you ahve)?

Comment: sorry - when I say "won't let me" ... it does let me, but it loses the starting dot.

Comment: Actually, Firefox version 70 does let me do this.

Comment: Thanks for checking, although I need this for our users and I can't guarantee what browser they'll be using.

Comment: It also works on Chrome. If you can't guarantee what browser they're using, then you may want to teach them how to do renaming in Explorer with extensions visible.