# using notepad++ to save file without name but not able using windows explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filenames

Why is it possible to create a file without a name i.e. .htaccess using notepad++, but when using windows explorer it requires a filename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has something to do with the way Microsoft allows `Explorer.exe` to work with saving files without a file name and just a file extension being specified.

It appears that some applications such as Notepad and Notepad++ do not have this limitation programmed into their logic, and they do allow saving files with just an extension—so this is a Windows Explorer security feature or function that enforces this not to occur by default at the program level.

[image]

**WORKAROUND**

A workaround is to add an extra dot at the end of the extension and Windows Explorer will allow it to be saved but it'll parse the trailing dot and save it without a file name and without the extra dot at the end.

So when you create it with Windows Explorer as `.htaccess.` it will not give the below error message, and allow you to save it just fine.

[image]

[image]

**RESOURCE:** *[How do I rename a file to .htaccess in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/56562/how-do-i-rename-a-file-to-htaccess-in-windows-7/)*

Answer (score 2):

Technically, a file like `.htaccess` has a name of `.htaccess` and no extension. This follows from the official documentation of "Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces" at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx.

> File and Directory Names
>
> All file systems follow the same general naming conventions for an individual file: a base file name and an optional extension, separated by a period.

Note that there is *always* a name, what's optional is only the extension. So if the complete filename starts with a dot, and has no other dots in it, then that's the *name* and there is *no* extension. The language of the spec leaves no room for a filename to exist which has an extension but no name.

This can be verified by creating a couple of files named `.htaccess` and `.htaccess.bak` in an otherwise empty directory, then running the following at a cmd prompt.

```
C:\etc>dir /a-d /b *.*
.htaccess
.htaccess.bak

C:\etc>dir /a-d /b *.
.htaccess
```

The first `dir` lists both files as expected, the second one (where `*.` matches files with *no* extension) lists `.htaccess` only.

As to Explorer, it seems to ignore the spec and follow its own rules. A file like `.htaccess` is displayed with both name = `.htaccess` *and* type = `HTACCESS file` as long as the extension is not registered. If the name matches a *known* extension then the name is left blank and the extension is considered to match e.g. a file `.cmd` is displayed with type = `Windows Command Script` and without a name (when using the default '*hide extensions for known file types*' setting).

Since displaying a blank name looks bad, Explorer must have decided to block such names outright from being created by itself. That much transpares from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/04/14/8389268.aspx.